# Howto build g++ from source *and* pass options to `configure`

Tags: debian, aptitude, gcc

I would like to rebuild g++ with my own specific settings.

Here is what I did so far:

```
sudo aptitude install build-dep g++-4.2
mkdir trial && cd trial
apt-get source g++-4.2
```

Now I want to configure my specific settings. For g++ this is normally done by e.g.

```
sh configure --prefix=/home/voku/testing
```

But unfortunately there is no `configure` script inside the download directory (and also no configure.ac).

Are there additional steps that I need to get the `configure` script?

What I am actually looking for is a way to say:

- get the source
- apply all the patches you like
- make that whole stuff ready to build

**EDIT**: I have also asked on Stack Overflow - but nobody seems to know there.

**EDIT**:
Probably I could run one of the tools that actually create the .deb package for g++.

Afterwards - that's what I assume - there will be the needed configure script.

But that sounds awful:

- build the g++ .deb package
- cleanup the whole stuff again
- then use the generated configure script with my own options
- then build again

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to rebuild the Debian package with different options, it's a bit more complicated, because the Debian packaging of GCC is quite complex.  In general, you would look for a `configure` call in `debian/rules`, but in the `gcc-4.2` source package the interesting action actually happens in `debian/rules2`.  Look for a variable called `CONFARGS` in there.  `debian/README.maintainers` is also a good read if you want to do serious hacking on the package.

Comment: I just came back to mention this, but you beat me to it, so +1 instead

Comment: @Peter: thanks a lot. This is the best answer I have seen so far!

Answer (score 2):

Try running [autoconf](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/) - that is the command that creates the configure script for most applications that use one.

EDIT:

This was a wild goosechase, the right answer was to edit debian/rules2

Comment: If that is unclear: you run autoconf by going to the source directory and just running autoconf with no arguments - if you have the right version and the right input files are there it just does the rest automatically.

Comment: @Justin: autoconf tells me: `autoconf: configure.in: No such file or directory`. Looking around via `find . -name configure.in` shows nothing.

Comment: any program using configure should have a configure.in file? as a shot in the dark you could try, as explained on this page http://developers.sun.com/solaris/articles/gnu.html autoscan; mv configure.scan configure.in; aclocal; autoconf

Comment: @Justin: a file called `configure.scan` is also not there

Comment: autoscan should output configure.scan automatically

Comment: @Justin: ah ok. I just cleanup up by getting a fresh source. And I did not run `autoscan` again.

Comment: Also, which version of Linux is this? My debian stable version of gcc-4.2-20080520 had the configure script etcetera inside the 7zipped tar archive which was not extracted by default.

Comment: @Justin: it is Debian-Lenny-64bit. And yes - I also have something like `gcc-4.2-orig.tar.gz` (sorry - I can't be more precise for the moment as I have just logged off from the remote server in my company. VPN seems to be stuck now...). But `orig` sounds like if it has not the debian patches applied.

Comment: see Peter Eisentraut's answer above, this was a wild goosechase.

Answer (score 0):

Usually it is

```
./configure
```

not just

```
configure
```

i.e. try

```
 ./configure  --prefix=/home/voku/non-productive
```

Comment: @Nicholaz: There is simply no configure script, nor configure.ac or something similar. Regarding `./configure` : that doesn't make a difference once you have the configure script. `sh configure` does the same.

Comment: why is this getting voted up? he never run "configure", as he said, "sh configure" is identical to "./configure" this answer has nothing to do with his situation.